# How to inject Vuetify into my custom vue plugin

Tags: vue.js, plugins, vuetify.js

I would like to create a Vue plugin with a function which programatically renders a Vue component. That component depends on Vuetify. Everything works fine if I use vanilla HTML/CSS in that component, but using Vuetify-related things in there (e.g. a ) does not work. I assume that I didn't inject vuetify itself into the component correctly.

In my custom component, I tried importing every Vuetify component separately, but without success. I also tried creating the component with the syntax: new Vue({vuetify}), but also without success.

```
import MyCustomComponent from '@/components/MyCustomComponent'
import vuetify from '@/plugins/vuetify';



export default {
  install(Vue, options) {
    function renderMyCustomComponent() {
        const CustomComponent= Vue.extend(MyCustomComponent)
        Vue.use(vuetify)
        let instance = new CustomComponent()
        instance.$mount()
        document.body.appendChild(instance.$el)
    }

    Vue.prototype.$renderMyComponent = renderMyCustomComponent
  }

}
```

The error message indicates, that vuetify (or at least some of it's properties) are not available in my component
`[Vue warn]: Error in getter for watcher "isDark": "TypeError: Cannot read property 'dark' of undefined"`

**HINT/EDIT**: I am using Vuetify 2.0. The way Vuetify is injected into the app changed a little bit. Here's the code of my vuetify plugin file:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify';
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css';
import de from 'vuetify/es5/locale/de';

Vue.use(Vuetify)

export default new Vuetify({
  theme: {
    themes: {
      light: {
        primary: '#3f51b5',
        secondary: '#b0bec5',
        accent: '#8c9eff',
        error: '#b71c1c'
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: Can you provide code of `'@/plugins/vuetify'`?

Comment: Just edited my post. Btw. I forgot to mention that I am using Vuetify 2.0.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure if you solved this issue, but I had the same problem where Vuetify in a plugin would not be initialized correctly.

Vuetify documentation states that you need to define a `vuetify` option when creating your vue instance:

```js
new Vue({
  vuetify,
}).$mount('#app')
```

Fortunately, custom Vue plugins has an options parameter that we can use.

Here is the code that consumes your plugin:

```js
const options = {}; // add other options here! (vuex, router etc.)
Vue.use(YourCustomPlugin, options);

new Vue(options).$mount('#app');
```

And here is your plugin code:

```js
import vuetify from "./src/plugins/vuetify";

export default {
    install(Vue, options) { // options is undefined unless you pass the options param!
        Vue.component('my-custom-component', MyCustomComponent);
        Vue.use(Vuetify);
        options.vuetify = vuetify;
    }
};
```

The `vuetify` module is very simple:

```js
import Vuetify from "vuetify";
import "vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css";

const opts = {}

export default new Vuetify(opts);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you actualy don't export plugin itself in `'@/plugins/vuetify'`;

```
import MyCustomComponent from '@/components/MyCustomComponent'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify';

export default {
  install(Vue, options) {
    function renderMyCustomComponent() {
        Vue.use(Vuetify)
        const CustomComponent= Vue.extend(MyCustomComponent)
        let instance = new CustomComponent()
        instance.$mount()
        document.body.appendChild(instance.$el)
    }

    Vue.prototype.$renderMyComponent = renderMyCustomComponent
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't solve my problem. It results in the same errors as before.

Comment: Have you tried to move `Vue.use()` before `Vue.extend`?